# in Server 2012 Group Policy how can I force all users to have password-locked screen savers?

Tags: windows-server-2012

This is how I have it configured:

[image: This is how I have it configured.] Some users have their screen savers password protected, other's don't. I made the change a week ago, plenty of time for the policy to propagate. Is it possible some of the users in the domain aren't configured to get policy updates?

While only some users have the password lock, all users are currently not able to edit their screen saver.

This is the first time I've ever done anything with group policy. The Domain Controller is Server 2012. The machines are Windows 7.

Edit: looks like it may be a bug in Server 2012: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2976965#appliesto, investigating...

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940428.aspx

Comment: @gtirloni is that for Win Server 2k? Anyway, I think I've already done that, as shown in the image. It just doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Did you actually link the GPO in question to a container or OU with users/computers in it?  If not, you need to do that; simply drag the GPO up to the container or OU you want to apply this to (apply it at the domain level by dragging it up to the name of your domain) and then give it a little bit to propogate down to your users.  If you've already linked it and I'm treating you like a total newb, then disregard this comment.

Comment: @BradBouchard yes, it's linked in the [CompanyName]Users organization unit. Just didn't expand that in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot isn't showing that you've linked that GPO anywhere.

Without linking the GPO to an OU it won't actually apply to computers or users.

I think some [background on Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307(v=ws.10).aspx) would probably help you out a lot.

Edit:

Running the Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) tool on a user where you hypothesize that your GPO settings are "taking" will show you if they really are. If the GPO isn't linked anywhere then you won't see it in an RSoP output.

In the case of this setting, which is a user setting, you'll want to link it at or above the OU where your user accounts are located. You could link this particular GPO to the top of the domain with no ill effects.

Comment: Are you sure? As I said " all users are currently not able to edit their screen saver." It appears that it did get applied. Or some of it did. I'm positive I was able to edit my screen saver prior to creation of that policy.

Comment: If you didn't link the GPO then it's not doing anything. An GPO that isn't linked doesn't do anything.

Comment: The GPO is linked in the CompanyNameUsers OU. I just didn't include it in the screenshot.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you on this, but perhaps you think it's linked.  Can you provide a screenshot of the linked GPO?

Comment: http://imgur.com/lUqjOyL I think it's a different issue, linked it in my OP

Comment: What I mean is, can you provide a screenshot of the OU/container where it's linked with that OU/container expanded?

Comment: http://imgur.com/uC0aSRc

Comment: RSoP output is going to be your friend here. Also, checking the Event Log on machines where you don't think Policy is applying properly.

Answer (score 2):

> @BradBouchard yes, it's linked in the [CompanyName]Users organization unit. Just didn't expand that in the screenshot. –  jcollum 5 mins ago

If that is, in fact, true, then you'll need to run some GP testing tools both server side and potentially client side.  There are two tools at the bottom of your screenshot that are located on the left-hand side of the screen called "Group Policy Modeling" and "Group Policy Results".  These tools will help you determine what, theoretically, will happen given a computer/users location/membership, and what actually is being applied.  Run them, starting with Group Policy Modeling followed by Group Policy Results to see what should happen to your users, and then you'll find out why things aren't happening as you predict.  Also, Scope will be a big factor here.  Have you left the Scope set to "Authenticated Users"?  If not, then do so, as any filtering of the Scope may cause some of your users to not obtain the settings from this GPO.